# How can I get ESLint VS Code extension to work on .mjs files?

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

I'm running into this weird issue where the ESLint VS Code extension doen't work on `.mjs` files. By "not working" I mean it's not showing any red squiggly lines or anything.

I know that there's a problem with that file because when I run `eslint` from the terminal, it shows me a few problems. Also, if I open a normal `.js` file it works just fine.

I googled this for a while but can't seem to find any specific configuration needed by the ESLint extension in order for it to work on `.mjs` files. I found a few github issues referring to eslint support for mjs, but those were for the CLI and they're more than five years old now.

I have ESLint installed locally to that project and my `.eslintrc` looks like this:

```
{
    "env": {
        "es6": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2022,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "import"
    ],
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "prettier"
    ]
}
```

The only configuration I have related to ESLint on my VSCode User `settings.json` is

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
},
"eslint.validate": ["javascript"]
```

So, is there a problem with the VSCode extension support for `.mjs`, or is it just some setting I'm missing?

PS: I'm using ESLint version ^8.38.0 and VSCode 1.77.1 b7886d7461186a5eac768481578c1d7ca80e2d21 x64

Comment: Hey, have you figured this ?

Comment: Nope. It was just a weeklong project, so I decided to live with it and run lint scripts on the CLI before commiting and pushing code.